# ExtJS Grid Not Displaying Rest Data

Tags: extjs, store

I have created a mini EXTJS app, defined a model, store, and grid. I have verified the store is working because I can use Chrome debug tools to create an instance and view the data. However, when I attempt to display the data in a grid it never shows.

Here is the code for the app.js:

```
Ext.application({
launch: function () {
    Ext.define('Companies', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['id', 'link', 'name']
    });

    Ext.define('CompaniesStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'Companies',
        storeId: 'cStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'http://corky52547.somee.com/Service1.svc/Companies'
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        name : "viewPort2",
        layout: 'fit',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Bill Reminder Web'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'grid',
                title: 'Bills',
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                columns: [
                    {text: 'ID', width: 100, dataIndex: 'id'},
                    {text: 'Link', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'link'},
                    {text: 'Name', width: 200, dataIndex: 'name'}
                ],
                store: Ext.create('CompaniesStore',{})
            }
        ]
    });
}
});
```

Update:

I am now able to get the data to display but like this with no theme. How do I update the theme?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS (Cross Origin requests) is blocking the request to domain.
Layout Fit is also causing some issues.

To get CORS working, you will need to add

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Otherwise, you can use middle-ware proxy like [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/)

Minor mistakes like field names should be matched with exact case they are available in response.

**Here is a working POC Code:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: "Application",
    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('Companies', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['ID', 'Link', 'Name']
        });

        Ext.define('CompaniesStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'Companies',
            storeId: 'cStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://corky52547.somee.com/Service1.svc/Companies'
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            name: "viewPort2",
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                title: 'Bill Reminder Web'
            }, {
                xtype: 'grid',
                title: 'Bills',
                flex: 1,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'ID',
                    width: 100,
                    dataIndex: 'ID'
                }, {
                    text: 'Link',
                    flex: 1,
                    dataIndex: 'Link'
                }, {
                    text: 'Name',
                    width: 200,
                    dataIndex: 'Name'
                }],
                store: Ext.create('CompaniesStore', {})
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

**Here is working fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gbc

Comment: I confirm this is working locally but I have additional follow up question. When I look at it in the fiddle it has the nice theme attached, Mine has not theme. I uploaded into the original question. How do I get the updated theme?

Comment: If you have created app with sencha cmd then you can edit app.json and change theme in it with defined themes (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/theming.html). If you are using it outside the box you should be able apply the them by importing theme css. In my case, with sencha fiddle, it is applying css out of box by including https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/6.0.1/build/classic/theme-crisp/resources/theme-crisp-all-debug.css in index.html